# How to populate combobox in a new window from datagrid mouse double click

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

```
     public partial class DataGrid_HBD : UserControl
{

    public DataGrid_HBD()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // 2 Seconds Timer before connecting to the Database.
        // This improves UI rendering on button click
        DataGrid_Data();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loading Data Grid
    /// </summary>
    public void DataGrid_Data()
    {
        // 2 second delay before loading DataGrid
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();

            // Attempt to connect to SQL Server database and populate DataGrid with database tables. 
            try
            {
                string connectionString = ("Data Source=\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [hb_Disputes].[DSP_ID], [hb_disputes].[ACCOUNT], [Users].[TX_EMPLOYEE], [hb_CsrNames].[NM_USER], [hb_disputes].[CUST_NAME],[hb_disputes].[PREM_ADDR], [hb_status].[Status], [hb_disputes].[OPENED], [hb_disputes].[DEADLINE], [hb_disputes].[DATERSLVD], [hb_rpttype].[ReportType], [hb_ratetype].[RateType], [hb_Disputes].[FR_DT_FIRSTREV], [hb_Disputes].[FR_TS_LATESTUPD], [hb_Disputes].[COMMENT], [hb_Disputes].[FR_DSP_CLSF], [hb_Disputes].[FR_CUST_CNTCT], [hb_Disputes].[FR_WRK_REQ], [hb_Disputes].[FR_OPN_ERR], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_TP], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_DTLS], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_DT_WNTD], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_ISSD_BY], [hb_Disputes].[FR_CMMNT] FROM [hb_disputes]" +
                    " LEFT JOIN [Users] ON [hb_disputes].[ASSGNTO] = [Users].[KY_USER_ID] LEFT JOIN [hb_CsrNames] ON [hb_disputes].[WFMUSER] = [hb_CsrNames].[KY_USER_ID] LEFT JOIN [hb_status] ON [hb_disputes].[STATUS] = [hb_status].[STSID] LEFT JOIN [hb_rpttype] ON [hb_disputes].[RPTTYPE] = [hb_rpttype].[RPTID] LEFT JOIN [hb_ratetype] ON [hb_disputes].[REV_CLS] = [hb_ratetype].[RTID]", connection);
                connection.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                connection.Close();

                dtGrid.DataContext = dt;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database connection is not available at this time. Please contact your database administrator ");
            }
         };
    }

    private void dtGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        // User double clicks on DataGrid Row
        // Open new Window
        // Populate selected textboxes with selected datarow
        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView row_selected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

        var windowToOpen = new Window1();

        if(gd !=null )
        {
            // Textboxes
            windowToOpen.txt_RowRecrd.Text = row_selected["DSP_ID"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_acctnumber.Text = row_selected["ACCOUNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_analyst.Text = row_selected["TX_EMPLOYEE"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_custname.Text = row_selected["CUST_NAME"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_address.Text = row_selected["PREM_ADDR"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_Status.Text = row_selected["Status"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_opened.Text = row_selected["OPENED"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_deadline.Text = row_selected["DEADLINE"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_revcls.Text = row_selected["RateType"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_WFMissuedBy.Text = row_selected["NM_USER"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_firstreview.Text = row_selected["FR_DT_FIRSTREV"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_Latestupdate.Text = row_selected["FR_TS_LATESTUPD"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_reviewNotes.Text = row_selected["FR_CMMNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_ResolutionNotes.Text = row_selected["COMMENT"].ToString();


            // Comboboxes
            windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedItem = row_selected["ReportType"].ToString();


            windowToOpen.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

When the user double clicks on a row in the Datagrid, it opens a new window and populates the textboxes with the selected cells. However, it does not work for CombinationBoxes. I attached an image of the new window (Window1) that the information is populating to. The image shows the code behind for the combobox with the populated table from the SQL Server database.

[image: Window1 Combobox code behind]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You must set `Datasource` of `cmb_UtilityRptTyp` with a list of available report types like this:

```
// Define ReportType Class
class ReportType {  
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }

  public ReportType(int id, string title)
  {  
    ID = id;  
    Title = title;  
  }  
}
```

Then set `DataSource` in first line of `dtGrid_MouseDoubleClick`:

```
ReportType[] list = new ReportType[] {  
  new ReportType(1, "Type 1"),  
  new ReportType(2, "Type 2"),  
};  

windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.DataSource = list;  
windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.DisplayMember = "Title";  
windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.ValueMember = "ID";
```

After that you must use the `SelectedText` instead of `Text` in `ComboBox`, like this:

```
windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedText = row_selected["RPTTYPE"].ToString();
```

Also, You can use `SelectedIndex`, to find item index you could `IndexOf` like this

```
string rptType = row_selected["RPTTYPE"].ToString();
int index = windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.Items.IndexOf(rptType );
windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedIndex = index;
```

Or use `FindStringExact`

```
string rptType = row_selected["RPTTYPE"].ToString();
int index = windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.FindStringExact(rptType );
windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedIndex = index;
```

Comment: These don't work. I used (                windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.ItemsSource = row_selected["ReportType"].ToString();) and it split each letter of the cell into a different item in the combobox. The combobox was aslo blank when the page loaded.

Comment: of corse ` windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.ItemsSource=row_selected["ReportType"].ToString();` is wrong. You must set `Datasource` with list of available report types.

Comment: I've changed the answer to more details. @IanMark

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really struggling with this. I added more code to show what I am attempting to do. Will I need to create a class? and type that values listed in the database? I'm also new to C#

Comment: @IanMark, you have to fill 'cmb_UtilityRptTyp' items before set selected items. You must call the code in the attached image in question before `windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedItem = row_selected["ReportType"].ToString();`

Comment: I've been looking up how to call in the code from another window. And I tried using                 (Application.Current.MainWindow as Window1).txt_UtilityRptTyp_Loaded(); but it's not working.

Comment: @IanMark 
1- Change modifire of `txt_UtilityRptTyp_Loaded` to public: `public void txt_UtilityRptTyp_Loaded ...`
2- After ` // Comboboxes` in your code add `windowToOpen.txt_UtilityRptTyp_Loaded(null, null);`

Comment: That did not work. It's loading the items into the Combobox as defined in the modifier (txt_UtilityRptType_Loaded). However, it's not showing the row selected from the DataGrid as it's doing for the textboxes. I think it's missing row_selected["ReportType"].ToString();

Comment: Please add `txt_UtilityRptTyp_Loaded` body as Code. @IanMark

Comment: That doesn't work as well. I get errors with  `cmb_UtilityRptTyp.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["t"].DefaultView;  cmb_UtilityRptTyp.DisplayMemberPath = "ReportType"; cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedValuePath = "RPTID"; ` And wouldn't doing this give me the same result as `windowToOpen.txt_UtilityRptTyp_Loaded(null, null);`?